# _bin_deployableassemblies from build server without visual studio 2010 SP1 installed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, teamcity, msbuild-4.0

I'm attempting to build a mvc 3 application that relies on the _bin_deployableassemblies folder introduced in VS2010 sp1.

I'm using TeamCity as my build server.

When I run the build within TeamCity from my dev machine which has VS2010sp1 installed, everything is fine.

When I run the build from the build server which does not have VS2010sp1 installed but does have TFS2010sp1 installed (and mvc3 for that matter), the _bin_deployableassemblies files are not processed.

How can I get the bits on the build server to make the _bin_deployableassemblies folder work?

Comment: Resolved by copying the full msbuild\microsoft\visualstudio folder from dev machine. Still curious to know if there is an install that will get these files updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by copying the full msbuild\microsoft\visualstudio folder from dev machine.